# Information Exposure through an Error Message using Response.Write

Tags: asp.net, xss, veracode

I have a class which inherits from a System.IO.StringWriter. A code snippet of the class is as shown below:

```
public class httpHelper : StringWriter
{
      private HttpResponse _httpResponse;

      public httpHelper(HttpResponse httpResponse)
      {
          _httpResponse = httpResponse;
      }

      public virtual void WriteText(string input)
      {
           _httpResponse.Write(input);
      }
}
```

A veracode scan showed that _httpResponse.Write(input) would cause "Information Exposure through a Error Message". Without mitigating this issue, is there a (alternative) way to resolve this issue? Would sanitizing the parameter "input" help? in that case, would encoding the input suffice? Please advice.

Comment: Just HTML encode the `input`. That might solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Yogeesh.I am still not sure encoding this would be the right approach since i do not know the input that would be passed. if the input is html, the rendering would not happen as desired.

Comment: Whatever data you are throwing on the webpage keep that `URL encoded` that would do the job.